# Some images can't be loaded, established connection being terminated

Tags: html, django, firefox

Some images can load perfectly, but some can't. The problem is, they are in the same directory, following a same naming pattern.
For example, this picture **can** load:

[image: loads fine]

but this can't:

[image: problem loading]

I'm expecting it to be something like this:

[image: the desired situation]

but actually, there turn out to be NOTHING. No broken-image icon, just gone, like it never existed:

[image: unexpected page]

but when I right clicked on the image link(from the source code panel) and opened it in a new tab, the image could be shown normally:

[image: can be opened in broswer]

It seems like that the broswer be like: "you know what, I don't want to work for no reason. Wait, you want to see this image so eagerly? Fine, fine, I will show it..."

Here is the html template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>{{ metamodel.metamodel_name }}</h1>
    {% for group in metamodel.group_set.all %}
    <h2>{{ group.group_name }}</h2>
    {% for product in group.product_set.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'exhibition:models' product.id %}">
        <img src="{{ product.picture.url }}">
        <p>{{ product.model }}</p>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</body>

</html>
```

The view function:

```
def show_products(request, metamodel_id):
    try:
        context = {
            'metamodel': Metamodel.objects.get(pk=metamodel_id),
        }
    except Metamodel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Metamodel Does NOT exist !")
    return render(request, 'exhibition/show_products.html', context)
```

djago server log:

```
Not Found: /favicon.ico
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 7419)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\John Smith\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\John Smith\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] A software in your PC terminated an established connection.
----------------------------------------
Not Found: /favicon.ico
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 7422)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\John Smith\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\John Smith\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] A software in your PC terminated an established connection.
```

I'm using Firefox 85 on Windows 10. I also tried to use the new Edge to view the same page and only to get the same result. Additionally, restart diango server does nothing helpful.

Comment: What's the request log in the network tab of the browser? Are the requests even reaching django? Do you see those requests in the django server log in command line terminal?

Comment: @xyres Added djago server log. Clearly something went wrong, but I don't how to solve that.

Comment: This log only shows the requests for `favicon.ico`. I feel this isn't the complete log. Start a new server, reload the page and then copy the whole log that's printed out after reloading the page.